# Как округлить число к меньшему при этом сохранив дробную часть в Python

Tags: python, round

Вопрос в том, как округлить число к меньшему, сохранив дробную часть. К примеру 2.71953 округлить до 2.71. Функция round округляет к большему, а у math.floor нельзя указать количество символов после запятой. Буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: это отбрасывание, а не округление

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import math
a = 2.71953
b = math.floor(a * 100)/100.0
```

или

```
b = round(a - 0.5/10**2, 2)
```

или

```
b = a // 0.01 / 100
```

или

```
b = a // 0.01 * 0.01
```

Скорость работы разных вариантов:

```
>>> import timeit as t
>>> N = 10000000

>>> t.timeit("math.floor(a * 100)/100.0", "import math; a = 2.71953", number=N) / N
2.2843667271081358e-07

>>> t.timeit("round(a - 0.5/10**2, 2)", "a = 2.71953", number=N) / N
4.7399221931118516e-07

>>> t.timeit("a // 0.01 / 100", "a = 2.71953", number=N) / N
1.7466544329654425e-07

>>> t.timeit("a // 0.01 * 0.01", "a = 2.71953", number=N) / N
1.3633709449786692e-07
```

Comment: спасибо, а ещё такой тогда вопрос: какой из этих вариантов быстрее и правильнее?

Comment: По правильности - одинаково. По скорости - добавил в ответ результаты измерений.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = input()
print(float(s[:s.find('.')+3] if '.' in s else s))

>>> 71.2245
>>> 71.22
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня так получилось сделать округление числа в меньшую сторону:

num = 25.2599854

print((int(num*100))/100)

<<<< 25.25

Comment: 1. переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык. 2. пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.