# Округлить [[25.28594]] в меньшую сторону до 2 знаков после запятой

Tags: python, numpy

Как округлить до 2 знаков после запятой?

Есть выражение:

```
num = [[25.28594]]
```

Нужен такой результат:

```
25.28
```

Моё решение кажется мне очень сложным для такой задачи:

```
import math

math.trunc(np.asscalar(np.array(num)) * 100) / 100
```

Первое улучшение:

```
np.asscalar(np.array(num)) // 0.01 / 100
```

**В итоге взял за образец:**

```
num.item() // 0.01 / 100
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1266457/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У функции `numpy.round` параметр `decimals` указывает, до какого знака округлять.

Вызов `np.round(num, 2)` возвращает либо число, либо массив из чисел, округлённых до второго знака после запятой.

Если вам нужно только одно число, то это можно сделать так: `np.round(num[0][0], 2)`

Answer (score 0):

Можно по простому
Создаем цикл из 5 шагов и проходимся по нашему числу, к пустой переменной прибавляем num[0], num[1] и т д, таким образом 5 первых элементов это и будет наше двузначное число, запятая, и два знака после неё

```
num = 25.28594
num2 = ''
for i in range(0,5):
    num2 += str(num)[i]
print(num2)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]